# Guardar un input en ionic 4

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

Soy nuevo en el tema y estoy intentando mostrar un ingreso que deposito en un input `<ion-input>`, pero el mismo me da nulo, lo vengo haciendo asi.

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-input id = "boton" type="number" placeholder="Ingresar numero documento" [(ngModel)]="numeroDoc"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Asi lo instancio, pero me da nulo:

```
const boton = document.querySelector('#boton');
```

Comment: Debes aprender cómo funcionan los formularios en Angular / Ionic, no es necesario acceder al elemento del DOM para obtener los valores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estimado,

Tu "*ion-input*" tiene eventos, uno de ellos se llama "*ionChange*", el cual llama a una función en tu archivo typescript (en este ejemplo: capturarNumeroDocumento() ), a esa función le pasas el evento ( $event ), por lo cual se debería ver similar a esto:

Archivo HTML:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-input id="boton" type="number" inputmode="numeric" placeholder="Ingresar numero documento" clearInput="true" (ionChange)="capturarNumeroDocumento( $event )"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

En el archivo TypeScript, capturas el evento, y lo manipulas a gusto, en el ejemplo te deje un "*console.log()*", para que veas cuál es la salida de este por consola.

Archivo TS:

```
public capturarNumeroDocumento( event: any ) {
    console.log(event); // Normalmente el valor se encuentra en ( event.detail.value )
}
```

La documentación oficial de los IonInput: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input